# Issue with Multiple JVM in desktop application

Tags: java, windows, architecture, jvm, system

We have a desktop application where we are packing Application Jar and JVM as well to avoid Java dependency in customer machine.

But issue is if the customer is having the Java installed alrieady in there system.we are facing issue like no class definition exception because of Java version dependencies.

Now my question is how to launch the application always with the JVM that are packed with Application and ensure it is not use the System JVM if it is installed.